# Pygments style not found

Tags: xcode, pygments

I have created a pygments style, which uses the same colors as xcode, and named it `xcode.py`:

```
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Keyword, Name, Comment, String, Error, \
     Number, Operator, Generic

class xcodeStyle(Style):
    default_style = ""
    styles = {
        Text:           '#000000',
        Comment:        '#008426',
        String:         '#D92823',
        Number:         '#2F2ECF',
        Keyword:        '#C22A9C',
        Name.Class:     '#753EA3'
    }
```

I tried placing it in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygments/styles` but when I list the available styles with

```
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
styles = list(get_all_styles())
print styles
```

my style doesn't get recognized. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes and no. I ended up going through the source code on BitBucket and found an xcode style built in. So I simply installed the source (v2.0 Beta) and that was it. I just checked and when running `pygmentize -L` in the terminal the new style is not even listed. So I guess pygmentize doesn't know it exists, but when I use the style it works. I use it in LaTex with the minted package and it works like a charm

Comment: I realised that I had already installed Pygments with Python 2, so my installed styles in the Python 3 directory were ignored, naturally, because the Python 2 `pygmentize` appears first in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's not quite clear how to add custom pygments style from their official docs. But I've figured it out after a while.

Sphinx has a conf.py parameter https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-pygments_style
Which could be a `fully-qualified name of a custom Pygments style class`. This is what we should use.

OK, the steps:

- Create a python module, e.g. `my_fancy_style.py` with your style class `MyFancyStyle`
- Put `my_fancy_style.py` in the same dir where your `conf.py` is located.
- Uncomment/write in `conf.py` lines, so sphinx will be able to find your class

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
# ...
pygments_style = 'my_fancy_style.MyFancyStyle'
```

That's it!